# Package dependencies error?

Tags: apt, 20.04, dependencies

```
This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.

Transaction failed: Package dependencies cannot be resolved
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:

libgirepository-1.0-1: Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.62.4-2~) but 2.64.6-1~ubuntu20.04.6 is to be installed
                       Depends: libc6 (>= 2.29) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.14 is to be installed
                       Depends: libffi7 (>= 3.3~20180313) but 3.3-4 is to be installed
libssl1.1: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.25) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.14 is to be installed
libssl1.1:i386: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.28) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.14 is to be installed
```

Comment: The most likely question ("what does this mean?") seems already answered in your output: `This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.` How to fix it depends upon what you did to cause it. These kinds of errors are almost always self-inflicted.